# Which version does Meteor's core Bootstrap package use?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, meteorite

The Meteor docs very blithely neglect to tell us what version the [core package of bootstrap](http://docs.meteor.com/#bootstrap) uses, and for the life of me I cannot find an answer to this seemingly simple question!!!

It *seems* like the core devs are awesome enough to keep it updated to the latest version (I want `3.1.1`!! It's so beautiful!!!!), but the presence of hack-it-yourself packages like [mangasocial / meteor-bootstrap-3](https://github.com/mangasocial/meteor-bootstrap-3) make me doubt that.

I want to use the core package, I want that reliability, but I also want the latest version. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of this writing, meteor ships with bootstrap v2.3.0, which you can see [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js). If you want to use 3.x, you'll need to use an atmosphere package like [bootstrap-3](https://github.com/mangasocial/meteor-bootstrap-3). If you want the absolute latest version, you can always run a [local package](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/local-packages).